# Error when creating the Client ID in Google api

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to create a Google Client ID to login with Gmail. While trying to create the login, I got below error.

As per the error, it is not ending with back slash. But still I am getting back slash error.
Am I missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned there

> For use with requests from a browser. This is the origin URI of the client application. It can't contain a wildcard (http://*.example.com) or a path (http://example.com/subdir). If you're using a nonstandard port, you must include it in the origin URI.

If you want to add a new redirect URl, you need to add it in the text area "AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI".
But in case of **javascript origins**, it is not for redirect uri, it contains origins where your app is allowed to access the Google APIs.(Origins cannot contain a wildcard or a path)
***It requires your site address.***
I myself use youtube api, have a look at this
[image: In this i have an error]
**But when i add the site address only, then error is vanished. Because, javascript origins contains origins where your app is allowed to access the Google APIs. I.e; Your site address.**
[image]

Even we can mention the port as well. Path to sub directories is not allowed.
[image]

**So, since your application is hosted on localhost with port 1234, just add this to your javascript origins:**

```
http://localhost:1234
```

Comment: I am still facing same issue: Origin URIs must not contain a path or end with "/" and I have added callback also

Comment: hey.You didn't get my answer. Sorry. You have to add the site address there only. Just add http://localhost:1234 @Pankaj

Comment: can u please suggest something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766977/get-email-address-from-socialite-while-login-with-gmail