# Get Email Address from socialite while login with Gmail

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I am following this article to **[login with Google](https://laravel-news.com/google-api-socialite)**. I am able to redirect to gmail login successfully. Also, it goes to callback url successfully.

**Below is my code**

```
public function showGoogleLoginForm() {
    $providerKey = \Config::get('services.google');
    return \Socialite::driver( 'google' )->scopes(['profile', 'email'])->redirect();
}
```

**Problem**

I am now trying to check if the callback gives me the email address of the user or not. So that, I could check that user is registered in my database or not.

Is there any way to get the email address in the callback?

I am able to redirect user to gmail login and also I am able to reach my callback method. In the callback method I got error on this code: `\Socialite::driver( 'google' )->user()`

I got this **[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zarwe.png)** when i used this code `\Socialite::driver( 'google' )->user();`

Comment: add those api tags too, like google people api besides laravel tags

Comment: did you check this : (from your above link) Google’s People API documentation seems to suggest that email addresses come back as part of a default query, but that doesn’t seem to be true. To resolve this, you need to add requestMask.includeField as a parameter in the request.

Comment: Can you share some sample code for the callback and redirect?

Comment: I have used java for these api's but i will still check.

Comment: check this and try it -> https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php

Comment: When I used socialite, I just created `UserSocial` entity and connected it to `User` entity on first login. Every next login just got user via the relationship.

Comment: I got this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/zarwe.png when i used this code `\Socialite::driver( 'google' )->user();`

Comment: Your error says about problems with project. Did you configure it correct?

Comment: I am able to redirect user to gmail login and also I am able to reach my callback method. In the callback method I got error on this code: `\Socialite::driver( 'google' )->user()`

Comment: You can't avoid text of the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t

Comment: I saw the answer referred by you above. Can you please confirm where can I find the Edit allowed referers? I am searching it in Api ->  Credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to enable Google + API to get rid of this error. Everything is working perfectly now.